# Solution of differential equation with complex coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given  $$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}-(3-2i)y=0,\quad y(0)=1,\quad y(x\rightarrow \infty)\rightarrow 0$$ then what is $y(\pi)$ ?

The answer given is $-e^{-\pi}$.

But I cannot understand how its solution can be pure real.

Comment: I would also like to know how $y(\pi)$ is calculated.

Comment: Are you sure about the $3-2i$ coefficient? How about $-3+4i$ instead?

Comment: I am sure about $3-2i$ but $y(\pi)$ may be $-e^{-2\pi}$.

Answer (score 1):

The general solution of
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-a^2 y=0$$
is
$$y=Ae^{ax}+Be^{-ax},$$
where $A$ and $B$ are constants. In this case, $a$ can be set as
$$a=\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{13}+3}{2}}+i\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{13}-3}{2}}$$
If $y(0)=1$, then $A+B=1$, and If $y(x\to\infty)\to 0$, then $e^{ax}$ must vanish, so $A=0$ and $B=1$. Then is it possible that $y(\pi)=-e^{-\pi}$? If the coefficient is $-3+4i$, as Yiorgos S. Smyrlis said, and $y(0)=-1$, then $-e^{-\pi}$ may be a possible solution.

Comment: how did you get $y=Ae^{ax}+Be^{-ax}$

Comment: $e^{ax}$ and $e^{-ax}$ satisfy $y''-a^2y=0$, and they are linearly independent. Since solution set of $y''-a^2 y=0$ is vector space and dimension of the set is 2, all solutions can be represented as linear combination of $e^{ax}$ and $e^{-ax}$. For detailed description, read textbooks associated with differential equations.

Answer (score 0):

Mainly, the answer is, why not?  Notice that the answer is not that $y$ is real for all values of $x$ (though maybe it is), just that $y$ is real for the specific value $x=\pi$.  You can have a very complicated looking complex function which will be pure real for certain values of the variable, for example,
$$ix^3-(3+5i)\sqrt2e^{i\pi/x^2}$$
when $x=2$.